# How many infinite subsets of the Naturals have natural density (asymptotic density) zero?

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory, probability-theory, asymptotics

Are there countably or uncountably many? I know that the set of all primes has density zero. Is there an obvious way of using that result to construct an uncountable family of such sets?

Comment: The asymptotic density of a subset of the primes is never greater than the asymptotic density of the primes.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that seems true if the limit exists for that subset. And does the limit exist for uncountably many subsets of the primes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: every subset of the primes has asymptotic density zero, and there are $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$ infinite subsets of the primes.

Comment: Same with every subset of the perfect squares or ...

Comment: ... any infinite set with asymptotic density zero. Yep.

Comment: Thank you Brian. Could you, per chance direct me to a reference of that fact? I am aware of the cardinality of the set of all subsets of the primes, but have no idea where to find the reference about their natural densities.

Comment: @prime4567: It's an immediate consequence of the definition of natural density: if $P$ is the set of primes, and $A\subseteq P$, then $|A\cap[n]|\le|P\cap[n]$| for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ (where $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$).

Comment: Thank you. I just thought the definition of asymptotic density includes the condition of the existence of the limit, and just because some superset may have natural density zero it doesn't immediatelly guarantee that the limit exists for all of it's subsets. Did I miss something?

Comment: @prime4567: In general you do have to worry about that, but not when the superset has density zero: in that case the limit exists by the squeeze theorem, since $0$ is a lower bound for $|A\cap[n]|/n$, and the upper bound of $|P\cap[n]|/n$ tends to zero.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @prime4567: You're welcome!